# calculate average letters in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, average

I need to calculate the average number of letters in each word from the user input. But I don't know how to do that. I know I need to find the total letters, then divide.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wordCount = countMethod(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(wordCount.ToString());
}
private int countMethod(string input)
{
    var separators = new[] { ' ', '.' };
    var count = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by average letters?

Comment: The average number of letters in each word

Comment: @Sam Please edit your question to reflect that - there's a difference between an average letter (nonsensical) and an average number of letters.

Comment: For each string you receive after the split, just put the length in a list and call `.Average()` (LINQ) on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LINQ `Average` to do this

```
private double AverageWordLetter(string input)
{
    var separators = new[] { ' ', '.' };
    var average = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Select(x=>x.Length).Average();
    return average;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.

```
var separators = new[] { ' ', '.' };
var words = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

decimal avg = words.Count() ==0? 0: (decimal) words.Sum(s=>s.Length)/(decimal)words.Count();
```

or, as `@dotctor` suggested (in comments) we could simply use `Average` extension.

```
var separators = new[] { ' ', '.' };
var words = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var avg = words.Select(s=>s.Length).Average();
```

Comment: Or use [Enuemrable.Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also there is no need to cast both sum and count to decimal. You can remove one of them.